# Cant edit values with functions

Tags: c, function

I try to edit value with function but the value retruns back. Here is my code:

```
int reverse(int number){
number *= 5;
printf("%d", number);

return number;
}
.
.
.
printf("Please enter an integer number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);
    // Reverse a number and assign it to the variable
    reverse(num);
    printf("Reversed number is: %d", reversed = num);
```

for example when I set number as 3 the output like:
15Revered number is: 3

But I want to make reversed value 15 too.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your main code throws away the returned value: `reverse(num);`.

You need to assign it to where you want it to go, for example: `num = reverse(num);`, or `int reversed_num = reverse(num);`.